# how to set height of gridView Builder according to Random list items we are getting

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

[can't able to scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfifH.png) how to set height of gridView Builder according to Random list items we are getting?
i want my GridView to be scrolled by SingleChildScrollView as i want to set my gridView to non Scrollable!! and set GridView's height according to the items.length(mealItem.length // given in code)

```dart
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
                child: Text(
                  "منتجات الالبان",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              // filter button
              Container(
                height: 45,
                width: 351,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                    color: Colors.black),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset("assets/filter.png",
                        height: 17, width: 16, color: Colors.white),
                    Text("تصنيف", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              // over
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                child: Text(
                  "الالبان",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              // meal Item of particular category
              Container(
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 3 / 4.5,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 18,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 24,
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                        child: Card(
                          elevation: 4,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: mealList.length,
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: whats the problem you're facing? Also you mention `ListView.builder` but the code is using `GridView.builder`

Comment: sorry it's by mistake

Comment: problem is  i already set physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), as i don't want my GridView Scrollable i want my gridView covering the height without scrollable   according to the items

Comment: and yes i am scrolling this GridView but with my SingleChildScrollView not with gridView

Comment: Okay and What happens now? Can you share a screen shot so we can understand better.

Comment: i don't have enough reputation  points can you share your number

Comment: I don't want to share my phone number here, but  you can find my profile for twitter and Github on my Stackoverflow Profile.

Comment: https://join.skype.com/invite/yaLS6abiXpV7

Comment: add me on skype